# Divide all numbers in dataframe for a constant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to divide all my dataframe values by 2233 (with precision of 2 decimal places)

How can I do that? I know that if it were a matrix, 2 nested loops could solve.

[image: My dataframe (it's very small)]

Comment: If your dataframe were actually a nested list, then yes, nested for loops would be fine. But because this is a pandas dataframe, which is backed by a numpy array, it is more efficient (and easier) to use vectorized approaches.

Comment: Applying a simple operation to all elements of a column, or even all columns of a data frame, is covered in many PANDAS tutorials.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can try

```
value=2233
df=(df/value).round(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use apply:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x/y)
```

Comment: This is an antipattern in pandas.